# Difference between imwrite and imsave

Tags: matlab

//1

I have color matrix(M*N)

and I used imsave to get an image.

figure,  imagesc(color matrix), colormap(gray); imsave;

It is simple and works.But I have to give image name to save image each time. 
How can I pass filename to imsave.

//2
imwrite() does the job what I want to do with imsave. How can I get MAP values(3*3) for gray scale image. Important thing I want to know is what is best imsave or imwrite for better quality image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a look at the code for `imsave` (run `edit imsave`), you'll see that it is basically a wrapper for `imwrite` that comes with a dialog. In other words, they both will write the same quality image.

To use [IMWRITE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/imwrite.html) with a map, use the following syntax:

```
imwrite(yourImageHere,map,filename)
```

Comment: What should be map value for gray image;  r=[0,0.5,1]',g=r;b=r;         Map=[r,g,b];                          Am I right???

Comment: @sayyad: If you only want the image to consist of three shades (white, gray, black), then yes, that sounds reasonable.